# Show output of controller in all page in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new in cakephp. I wanted to build a menu system for my site. Is there anyway to show that controller output view in entire site ? My controller like this:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class MenusController extends AppController {

// I want to show all avilable controller in my application
public $components = array('ControllerList');

public function index() {    
        $this->set('menus', $this->ControllerList->getList());
    }    
}
```

And my view :

```
 foreach ($dataForView['menus'] as $key => $val) {

      if ($val['name'] == 'Menus') {
            unset($val['name']);
            unset($val['actions']);
             }
      else { 
          echo '<li class="dropdown">';
          echo "<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>".$val['name'].'<b class="caret"></b></a>' ;

          echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';

        foreach ($val['actions'] as $key => $value) {
          echo '<li><a href="#">'. $value .'</a></li>';
          if ($value == 'add') {
           break;
          }
        }
    echo "</li></ul>";
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options you have is to make `ControllerList` a component of `AppController` and
set the `menus` property in the `beforeFilter` method of `AppController`.

Example:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array(
        'ControllerList'    
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->set('menus', $this->ControllerList->getList());
    }
}
```

[CakePHP Controller Callbacks docs here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks)

As for the view you should create the menu as an element and include it once in your layout.

Example:

```
app/View/Element/main_menu.ctp:

foreach ($dataForView['menus'] as $key => $val) {
... // your code here
}
```

And you include this in your layout (app/View/Layouts/default.ctp for example)

```
<?php echo $this->element('main_menu'); ?>
```

[CakePHP Element docs here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I will try it & let you know. One more suggestion .. How can I change $dataForView with my model name or controller name ?

Comment: Thank you very much.. It's working 100% :) . But will you please describe why data are sending in $dataForView ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what exactly you want to know?!

Comment: I am using $dataForView['menus'] for viewing data as output. But I have another controller but it's passing data like this $userinfo['userinfo'] . Why this difference ?

Comment: You should access the data using the name from $this->set('name_here', $value_here); So you should actually do foreach($menus as $key => $val) { .. }

Comment: There is no difference. Every property set using $this->set will also be available in $dataForView. But you should use the property name that you provided in $this->set(..)

Comment: Thank you very much :) .. You helped me to lean new things. Was in confusion but now it's clear :)